# Why is the individual dictionary being printed in output in the following code not the same as the one being added?

Tags: python

So, I have a JSON file, with some elements in it. The end goal of the code is to generate 3 elements for each element in the JSON file, with some modified properties, but not all.

The way I went about this is to run a for loop and have 3 different parts of code block generating the required elements, and adding it to an empty list. But for some reason, I the elements I am generating aren't the ones being added to the final list.

Specifically, the "label" sub element gets messed up. Can someone please explain why's that happening?

Here's the code:

```
from math import sqrt
import json
import gc

with open("your-path here\\inclined-conveyors.json") as f:
    conv_json = json.load(f)

#print("conv_json['conv'] object is: \n\n\n", conv_json['conv'])

modified_conv = list()

for item in conv_json["conv"]:
    new_x_coordinate_delta = (item['height']) / (2*sqrt(3))
    new_y_coordinate_delta = item['height'] / 6

    addendum1 = item.copy()
    addendum1['name'] = addendum1['name'][:6] + "A"
    addendum1['displayName'] = addendum1['name']
    
    new_x_coordinate = addendum1['x'] + new_x_coordinate_delta    
    new_y_coordinate = addendum1['y'] - new_y_coordinate_delta
    
    addendum1['x'] = round(new_x_coordinate, 6)
    addendum1['y'] = round(new_y_coordinate, 6)

    addendum1['label']['x'] = round(new_x_coordinate, 6)
    addendum1['label']['y'] = round(new_y_coordinate, 6)
    addendum1['height'] = addendum1['height'] / 3
    print("\n addendum1 is: ", addendum1)
    empty_list = []
    empty_list.append(addendum1)
    modified_conv.extend(empty_list)
    # modified_conv.append(addendum)
    
    del addendum1
    del empty_list
    gc.collect()
    # print("added item from x == 1")
    # print("\n modified conv is: ", modified_conv)


    addendum2 = item.copy()
    addendum2['name'] = addendum2['name'][:6] + "B"
    addendum2['displayName'] = addendum2['name']
    
    addendum2['label']['x'] = addendum2['x']
    addendum2['label']['y'] = addendum2['y']
    addendum2['height'] = addendum2['height'] / 3
    print("\n addendum2 is: ", addendum2)
    empty_list = []
    empty_list.append(addendum2)
    modified_conv.extend(empty_list)
    # modified_conv.append(addendum)
    # modified_conv = modified_conv + addendum
    del addendum2
    del empty_list
    gc.collect()
    # print("added item from x == 2")
    # print("\n modified conv is: ", modified_conv)

    
    addendum3 = item.copy()
    addendum3['name'] = addendum3['name'][:6] + "C"
    addendum3['displayName'] = addendum3['name']
    #addendum3['displayName'] = ""

    new_x_coordinate = addendum3['x'] - new_x_coordinate_delta
    new_y_coordinate = addendum3['y'] + new_y_coordinate_delta
    addendum3['x'] = round(new_x_coordinate, 6)
    addendum3['y'] = round(new_y_coordinate, 6)
    addendum3['label']['x'] = round(new_x_coordinate, 6)
    addendum3['label']['y'] = round(new_y_coordinate, 6)
    addendum3['height'] = addendum3['height'] / 3
    print("\n addendum3 is: ", addendum3)
    empty_list = []
    empty_list.append(addendum3)
    modified_conv.extend(empty_list)
    # modified_conv.append(addendum)
    # modified_conv = modified_conv + addendum
    del addendum3
    del empty_list
    gc.collect()
    # print("added item from x == 3")
    # print("\n modified conv is: ", modified_conv)
            
        # modified_conv["conv"].append(item)

print("\n\n\n modified conv is: \n\n\n", modified_conv)
print("\n\n\ number of items in json is: ", len(conv_json['conv']))
print("\n\n number of items in modified conv is: ", len(modified_conv))
```

Here is a sample JSON:

```
{
    "conv": [
        {
            "className": "ConveyorStraight",
            "name": "P42700B",
            "displayName": "P42700",
            "type": "Straight",
            "x": 1511,
            "y": 2891.5,
            "label": {
                "x": 1511,
                "y": 2891.5,
                "size": 20,
                "rotation": 0
            },
            "height": 360,
            "width": 50,
            "rotation": 60,
            "searchable": true,
            "controlled": true
        },
        {
            "className": "ConveyorStraight",
            "name": "P42600B",
            "displayName": "P42600",
            "type": "Straight",
            "x": 1621,
            "y": 2891.5,
            "label": {
                "x": 1621,
                "y": 2891.5,
                "size": 20,
                "rotation": 0
            },
            "height": 360,
            "width": 50,
            "rotation": 60,
            "searchable": true,
            "controlled": true
        },
        {
            "className": "ConveyorStraight",
            "name": "P42500B",
            "displayName": "P42500",
            "type": "Straight",
            "x": 1731,
            "y": 2891.5,
            "label": {
                "x": 1731,
                "y": 2891.5,
                "size": 20,
                "rotation": 0
            },
            "height": 360,
            "width": 50,
            "rotation": 60,
            "searchable": true,
            "controlled": true
        },
        {
            "className": "ConveyorStraight",
            "name": "P42400B",
            "displayName": "P42400",
            "type": "Straight",
            "x": 1861,
            "y": 2892.5,
            "label": {
                "x": 1861,
                "y": 2892.5,
                "size": 20,
                "rotation": 0
            },
            "height": 360,
            "width": 50,
            "rotation": 60,
            "searchable": true,
            "controlled": true
        },
        {
            "className": "ConveyorStraight",
            "name": "P42300B",
            "displayName": "P42300",
            "type": "Straight",
            "x": 1971,
            "y": 2892.5,
            "label": {
                "x": 1971,
                "y": 2892.5,
                "size": 20,
                "rotation": 0
            },
            "height": 360,
            "width": 50,
            "rotation": 60,
            "searchable": true,
            "controlled": true
        },
        {
            "className": "ConveyorStraight",
            "name": "P42200B",
            "displayName": "P42200",
            "type": "Straight",
            "x": 2081,
            "y": 2892.5,
            "label": {
                "x": 2081,
                "y": 2892.5,
                "size": 20,
                "rotation": 0
            },
            "height": 360,
            "width": 50,
            "rotation": 60,
            "searchable": true,
            "controlled": true
        },
        {
            "className": "ConveyorStraight",
            "name": "P42100B",
            "displayName": "P42100",
            "type": "Straight",
            "x": 2211,
            "y": 2892.5,
            "label": {
                "x": 2211,
                "y": 2892.5,
                "size": 20,
                "rotation": 0
            },
            "height": 360,
            "width": 50,
            "rotation": 60,
            "searchable": true,
            "controlled": true
        },
        {
            "className": "ConveyorStraight",
            "name": "P42000B",
            "displayName": "P42000",
            "type": "Straight",
            "x": 2321,
            "y": 2892.5,
            "label": {
                "x": 2321,
                "y": 2892.5,
                "size": 20,
                "rotation": 0
            },
            "height": 360,
            "width": 50,
            "rotation": 60,
            "searchable": true,
            "controlled": true
        },
        {
            "className": "ConveyorStraight",
            "name": "P41900B",
            "displayName": "P41900",
            "type": "Straight",
            "x": 2431,
            "y": 2892.5,
            "label": {
                "x": 2431,
                "y": 2892.5,
                "size": 20,
                "rotation": 0
            },
            "height": 360,
            "width": 50,
            "rotation": 60,
            "searchable": true,
            "controlled": true
        },
        {
            "className": "ConveyorStraight",
            "name": "P41800B",
            "displayName": "P41800",
            "type": "Straight",
            "x": 2561,
            "y": 2892.5,
            "label": {
                "x": 2561,
                "y": 2892.5,
                "size": 20,
                "rotation": 0
            },
            "height": 360,
            "width": 50,
            "rotation": 60,
            "searchable": true,
            "controlled": true
        },
        {
            "className": "ConveyorStraight",
            "name": "P41700B",
            "displayName": "P41700",
            "type": "Straight",
            "x": 2671,
            "y": 2892.5,
            "label": {
                "x": 2671,
                "y": 2892.5,
                "size": 20,
                "rotation": 0
            },
            "height": 360,
            "width": 50,
            "rotation": 60,
            "searchable": true,
            "controlled": true
        },
        {
            "className": "ConveyorStraight",
            "name": "P41600B",
            "displayName": "P41600",
            "type": "Straight",
            "x": 2781,
            "y": 2892.5,
            "label": {
                "x": 2781,
                "y": 2892.5,
                "size": 20,
                "rotation": 0
            },
            "height": 360,
            "width": 50,
            "rotation": 60,
            "searchable": true,
            "controlled": true
        },
        {
            "className": "ConveyorStraight",
            "name": "P41500B",
            "displayName": "P41500",
            "type": "Straight",
            "x": 2911,
            "y": 2892.5,
            "label": {
                "x": 2911,
                "y": 2892.5,
                "size": 20,
                "rotation": 0
            },
            "height": 360,
            "width": 50,
            "rotation": 60,
            "searchable": true,
            "controlled": true
        },
        {
            "className": "ConveyorStraight",
            "name": "P41400B",
            "displayName": "P41400",
            "type": "Straight",
            "x": 3021,
            "y": 2892.5,
            "label": {
                "x": 3021,
                "y": 2892.5,
                "size": 20,
                "rotation": 0
            },
            "height": 360,
            "width": 50,
            "rotation": 60,
            "searchable": true,
            "controlled": true
        },
        {
            "className": "ConveyorStraight",
            "name": "P41300B",
            "displayName": "P41300",
            "type": "Straight",
            "x": 3131,
            "y": 2892.5,
            "label": {
                "x": 3131,
                "y": 2892.5,
                "size": 20,
                "rotation": 0
            },
            "height": 360,
            "width": 50,
            "rotation": 60,
            "searchable": true,
            "controlled": true
        },
        {
            "className": "ConveyorStraight",
            "name": "P41200B",
            "displayName": "P41200",
            "type": "Straight",
            "x": 3261,
            "y": 2892.5,
            "label": {
                "x": 3261,
                "y": 2892.5,
                "size": 20,
                "rotation": 0
            },
            "height": 360,
            "width": 50,
            "rotation": 60,
            "searchable": true,
            "controlled": true
        },
        {
            "className": "ConveyorStraight",
            "name": "P41100B",
            "displayName": "P41100",
            "type": "Straight",
            "x": 3371,
            "y": 2892.5,
            "label": {
                "x": 3371,
                "y": 2892.5,
                "size": 20,
                "rotation": 0
            },
            "height": 360,
            "width": 50,
            "rotation": 60,
            "searchable": true,
            "controlled": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Note the "minimal" in [mre].

Comment: Try using a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems#:~:text=A%20debugger%20is%20a%20program,while%20your%20program%20is%20running.) to figure out what's happening.